# Unable to overcome the "invalid wire type" when using protocol buffers with GTFS data

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to consume Google's GTFS Data, but get this error when trying to parse the downloaded stream from the GTFS api

This is the setup:

- I downloaded 'gtfs.proto' file which should define the message classes of realtime transit feed data from here https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/gtfs-realtime-proto

you can open this file with notepad, it says it is version 2.0

- I downloaded a windows 64 bit pre-compiled version of protoc, from here: 
  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/2.5.0/

I run the executable downloaded which generates a java package that should be useable later, by suppying my downloaded proto file as follows:

```
protoc-2.5.0-windows-x86_64.exe --proto_path=. --java_out=. gtfs.proto
```

- I started a Java project, and included the package which the previous step generated, and..
- I downloaded the protobuf version 2.5 runtime java library from the Maven repository - here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0
- I included this run time library into my project
- I made a REST call (using different technology) to get a stream of data from the transit provider I am wanting to interface to. I placed this stream in c:\temp\GTFSR.data, it is what I will use as source data.

I build a main() method designed to open the data, and pull out transit update records as follows:

```
import com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime.FeedEntity;
import com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class GtfsRealtimeExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  File file = new File("c:/temp/GTFSR.data"); 
  FeedMessage feed = FeedMessage.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(file));

  for (FeedEntity entity : feed.getEntityList()) {
       if (entity.hasTripUpdate()) {
          System.out.println(entity.getTripUpdate());
       }
   }
  }
}
```

When I run this, however, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:99)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:498)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(AbstractMessage.java:508)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$ExtendableMessage.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:661)
    at com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime$FeedHeader.<init>(GtfsRealtime.java:1234)
    at com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime$FeedHeader.<init>(GtfsRealtime.java:1217)
    at com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime$FeedHeader$1.parsePartialFrom(GtfsRealtime.java:1291)
    at com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime$FeedHeader$1.parsePartialFrom(GtfsRealtime.java:1)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:309)
    at com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime$FeedMessage.<init>(GtfsRealtime.java:154)
    at com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime$FeedMessage.<init>(GtfsRealtime.java:126)
    at com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime$FeedMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(GtfsRealtime.java:203)
    at com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime$FeedMessage$1.parsePartialFrom(GtfsRealtime.java:1)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:200)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:217)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:223)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime$FeedMessage.parseFrom(GtfsRealtime.java:400)
    at GtfsRealtimeExample.main(GtfsRealtimeExample.java:20)
```

I've tried this with the most recent releases of protoc (version 3), and the corresponding v3 of the runtime library, but get the same result.

What am I doing wrong ?!!

Comment: There are multiple reasons for invalid wire type problems. 1) the data isn't actually protobuf (perhaps compressed etc?) 2) the data has become corrupted (I see this a lot, usually by treating it as text) 3) the data is valid but you're using the wrong root object type; I'd try snagging the raw payload as bytes, and run it through https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode - this will tell you whether it is actually valid protobuf, and the *shape* may help you identify the correct root type